# Error when sending an audio file from my app to WhatsApp

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

For some time I've been trying to implement the functionality of sending an audio file from my app through WhatsApp. When debugging everything seems to work correctly in the application, the audio file is generated and saved correctly in the external storage of the device, the WhatsApp window opens and allows me to select the chat to which I want to send the audio. The problem is that when I press the send button, WhatsApp returns the message "Failed to share. Please try again" (I leave a screenshot of the error so that it can be better viewed, in addition to the code used to add said functionality).

Capture of the error shown on the screen by WhatsApp when trying to share the audio:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZuLt.jpg

Code used:

```
//////Boton//////

btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        try {
            String mediaPath = copyFiletoExternalStorage(R.raw.audio1, "audio1.mp3");
            File myFile = new File(mediaPath);
            Uri newUri = getUriForFile(wspActivity.this, "com.restart.shareaudiofiles.fileprovider", myFile);
            Intent compartirAudio = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            compartirAudio.setType("com.whatsapp");
            compartirAudio.setType("audio/mp3");
            compartirAudio.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,newUri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(compartirAudio, "Compartir vía"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Whatsapp no se encuentra instalado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});

/////funcion auxiliar/////
private String copyFiletoExternalStorage(int resourceId, String resourceName){
        String pathi= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/myProject/";
        boolean exists = (new File(pathi)).exists();
        if (!exists) {
            new File(pathi).mkdirs();
        }
        String pathSDCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/TeLoResumoBotonera/" + resourceName;
        try{
            InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            out = new FileOutputStream(pathSDCard);
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            int read = 0;
            try {
                while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buff, 0, read);
                }
            } finally {
                in.close();
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  pathSDCard;
    }

/////Elementos agregados al manifest/////

    <queries>

        <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
        <package android:name="com.whatsapp.w4b" />

    </queries>


    <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.restart.shareaudiofiles.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

I researched and implemented various resources to the manifest such as the fileprovider and queries with specific packages for WhatsApp (as can be seen in the code). However, the app still doesn't work. This makes me think that the problem could be in the mobile device that I am using to test the application (I would like to use another one to rule out this option, but I don't have an extra one). If the device has nothing to do with it, then clearly there is a bug in my code. Due to this, in case someone manages to identify the improvement that could make the application work correctly, I would be very grateful if you can share it with me, or at least give me an idea of ​​where to address the problem.

Comment: `return pathSdCard` Even if there is an exception in that function you return that path. But it will not be valid then. Please adapt your code. And the caller should check.